# Why when i'm parsing a website i'm getting old data from site and sometimes current data in site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website and i'm retrieving a table and a line of date.
Everything works fine but when i run my script i'm getting the current data from the site and sometimes i'm getting yesterday values from the site.

When i'm entering the site the data is always updated.

This is part of my code, full code is at:
http://pythonfiddle.com/lme

```
url = 'https://www.lme.com/en-gb/metals/non-ferrous/#tabIndex=0'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
dateFromSite = soup.find('div', class_='delayed-date').text.strip()
```

Comment: I'm always getting `Data valid for  2 June 2020`. Is this correct?

Comment: *Probably* it's caching a version of the page which may contain old data, and uses AJAX to fetch updated numbers. But that's anyone's guess…

Comment: Yes, but i'm getting sometimes Data valid for 1 June 2020

Comment: Added the full code at the description

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTTP headers obtained from the page, the site is using Cloudflare for caching the requests. So sometimes you get "old" version of the page.

You can try to circumvent this using http `'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'` header and/or using random parameter added to the url.

For example:

```
import time

url = 'https://www.lme.com/en-gb/metals/non-ferrous/?_random_number={rn}#tabIndex=0'
headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate'}

r = requests.get(url.format(rn=time.time()), headers=headers)
#print(r.headers) # should print 'CF-Cache-Status': 'MISS' in headers
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
dateFromSite = soup.find('div', class_='delayed-date').text.strip()

print(dateFromSite)
```